# how to skip_before_filter only for json format in rails 3?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rabl

How to `skip_before_filter` for **`index`** and **`show`** controller only if the format is `__json__` and not html?
Something like

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show, :format => :json]
```

I'm using **rails 3.2**.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show] , :if =>
 request.format.json? == true

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any other method?

Comment: Try this  skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show] , :if => proc {|c| request.xhr?}

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => [:index, :show] , :if =>
 request.content_type == "json"
```